# Repeat the values of each column twice and put them beside each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df and I want to repeat the values of each olumn 2 times. Here is an example:

```
data = {
    'id': [1],
    'v_1': [103],
    'v_2': [105],
    'v_3': [102],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and here is the output I want (the name of the columns are not important)

```
    id  v_1     v_11    v_2     v_22    v_3     v_31
    1   103     103     105     105     102     102
```

Can you please help me with this? Thank you

Comment: Try `df['v_11'] = df['v_1']` and so on.

Comment: My df has millions columns!

Comment: Pandas isn't intended to be used with millions of columns and one row. It's optimized for the opposite - few columns, millions of rows.

Comment: Thanks for this point. But I am happy with my df! So, for a df with 100 columns and miliion rows, this is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming column names are not important, we can use `index.repeat`

```
df.reindex(columns=['id', *df.columns.drop('id').repeat(2)])
```

---

```
   id  v_1  v_1  v_2  v_2  v_3  v_3
0   1  103  103  105  105  102  102
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. Changing the name of columns is easy part.

Comment: If "Id" is always first, `df.reindex(columns=df.columns.repeat(2)[1:])` might be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This option:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    'id': [1],
    'v_1': [103],
    'v_2': [105],
    'v_3': [102],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


for col in df.columns:
    
    df[f"{col}"+"1"] = df[col]


 df.columns = sorted(df.columns)
print(df)

id  v_1  v_2  v_3  id1  v_11  v_21  v_31
0   1  103  105  102    1   103   105   102
```

Comment: I don't believe OP wants the `id` column to be repeated as well. Perhaps `df.columns[1:]` would suffice then to skip over the `id` column.

Answer (score 0):

I have only managed to create the empty dataframe using the following code

```
list=['id']
for i in df.columns[1:] : 
  list.append(i)
  list.append(i+"_"+i[-1:3])
list
df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=list)
df2
```

Sorry it's my first post here.
This gives the following dataframe

```
id  v_1 v_1_1   v_2 v_2_2   v_3 v_3_3
```

Comment: Hmm or make it a dict and assign the value to original name, and also assign it to the duplicate. But this should be easy enough, so looks like a reasonable answer to point to the solution